# When to create a new EntityManager

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

I'm working with JPA (Eclipselink) in an unmanaged (no EJBs) context.

My question is: How long should I keep a Entity Manager open?

Swing Application:
- One open Entity Manager as long as the application is running
- Each single action a new Entity Manager

Web Application:
- One Entity Manager per (distinct) action
- One per request
- One per session
- One per application(-scope), asuming the application is thread safe

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Swing application, I will opt for the one `EntityManager` per action since it's quite cheap to create one and you might not want to keep so many entites managed by `EntityManager` when you're not using it (this is One `EntityManager` per application).

For the Web application, typical pattern used is "OpenSessionInView" pattern (`Session` applied to Hibernate but it can be applied to `EntityManager` as well since both are logically providing the same role/functionality).

More info here:
https://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView

Hope this helps.

Comment: Open Session In View (OSIV) is actually an anti-pattern. See [this post](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-open-session-in-view-anti-pattern/) for further discussion.

Answer (score 0):

One entity manager per request should be normal. But they should work through some connection pool.